# How to close a view class to return to the parent activity?

Tags: android, view, android-activity

I have an activity (MyActivity1) which starts a view class (MyView1) using `setContentView();`

In MyView1, after some drawings with canvas, I want to be able to return to MyActivity1. I tried `MyView1.this.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE)` or `View.GONE` but these just make the screen blank.

I also tried `((Activity)getContext()).finish();` but it creates a runtime error.

I should say that the back button works fine and pressing it closes MyView1 and brings the activity back. However, I want to be able to do that programmatically inside the view. for example I want when user touches a specific part of the screen in the view class, it closes itself and brings back the parent activity. How should I implement this?

It seems a very simple task! but I could not find the answer after searching through the similar questions.

Here is the way MyActivity1 starts the view:

```
public class MyActivity1 extends Activity {

MyView1 View1;


public void Start_Button(View view)
{

    Context ctx = getApplicationContext();
    View1= new MyView1(ctx, null);
    setContentView(View1);



}
}
```

and the part in MyView1 where I want to write something to close itself and bring MyActivity1 back:

```
public class MyView1 extends View {

 static Context mycontext;

  public MyView1(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {

    super(context, attrs);
            mycontext=context;

      }


   @Override
     public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

         this.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        ((Activity) mycontext).setContentView(R.layout.activity_myactivity1);
        // This gives runtime error

        }
}
```

Comment: You have no idea what the difference is between an Activity and a View, right? Otherwise you would just use two activities, one containing your normal layout and one your special view...

Comment: That special view contains onDraw method for drawings with canvas so I think it should be inside View. I believe you meant enclosing View inside another activity.

Comment: Like I thought, you don't know the difference...

Comment: can you introduce a link where the difference is clearly described? just for future viewers!

Comment: Basically just check the official guide. To make it short: One activity is a container for views. So if you have, for example, a registration form don't switch views to show a success/failure view. Instead start a new activity that is responsible for this purpose alone. Well with fragments you might consider replacing, but a fragment is just a layer between layout (views) and activities...

Comment: Thank you! In my case the view is a game window. it is possible to put this view into a dummy activity. but the selected solution by @HoanNguyen seems simple enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public public MyView1(Activity activity, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
            myActivity=activity;

      }  

 public void Start_Button(View view)
{

View1= new MyView1(this, null);
setContentView(View1);

}
```

Just call `myActivity.setContentView(R.layout.original_layout_for_MyActivity1);`

Comment: won't work since: The method setContentView(int) is undefined for the type MyView1.
I think setContentView can be called just from an activity class not a view class.

Comment: In your MyView1 have a constructor that have an Activity parameter. Save the pass in value in a class member and use this member to call setContentView.

Comment: you mean saving the context to a global object and use the mycontext for setContentView? I edited the code as I understood you but still I get the run time error.